# Django Related name not working

Tags: python, django

i have a model with

```
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="get_profile")
```

say 'obj' is a user object
 then if i call

```
obj.get_profile.country
```

It says

```
Author has no get_profile.
```

Using django 1.6

Comment: there is no need to use `related_name` when using `OneToOne`. Just can do `obj.user` and access it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Author has no get_profile.
```

Error suggests that obj is instance of `Author` model not `User` model.Make sure you are using `User` model instance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give us any context, but I will speculate that you retrieve said `obj` from request, i.e. `obj = request.user`. In that case instance you get might be either `User` or [`AnonymousUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object). If that is the case, you should check that:

```
user = request.user
if user.is_authenticated():
    # some code here
```

Comment: I get **RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /.../
myModel has no theRelatedName.**